# Maps containing themselves

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, std

currently I'm struggling with maps which should contain themselves. But I don't know the depth of the nesting when compiling.

```
std::map<Key, std::map<Key, std::map<Key, std::map<Key, ...>>>>
```

Is there a way to achieve this goal without infinitely repeating myself?

Comment: No. If it doesn't make logical sense you can't represent it in code.

Comment: No, you probably can't do it. For a self-referential structure like this, you probably need a map that contains a pointer to a map. Also note that to contain any meaningful information, that probably needs to be something like a struct/class/union so it can also contain something else (some actual data).

Comment: Right, the 'last' map of them should contain a Value. Thanks, I'll try to think of something else.

Comment: I suppose you don't want to declare a map data with this structure. Want you to put *instance* of map in another map or into itself?

Comment: What is the original problem you are trying to solve? Perhaps we can suggest a more appropriate data structure.

Comment: Right, I want an instance of a map in another map.

Actually I tried to create some kind of tree (with a map instead of a list for childnodes) and I somehow wasn't able to declare such a structure.

Comment: You could use some metaprogramming techniques to actually generate this via recursive templating - whether it would be useful or sane, remains an open question. In C++ you can do a lot of things that are neither useful nor sane.

Comment: *Why* do you want "an instance of a map in another map?" Please describe the problem that you think your map solves.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Well, David Rodríguez' answer describes what I first wanted to implement. But then I thought that it could probably work without a new class/struct, but like I was told here, a new class seems to be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The golden hammer for self-referential data structures is the use of pointers. In your particular, case, to implement a tree you can just do that:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
struct Node {
   Value data;
   std::map< Key, std::shared_ptr<Node> > child;
// ...
};
```

Each node in the tree contains a value and a set of child `Node`s maintained though a map of shared pointers. The `std::map` requires (according to the standard) the stored types to be complete, but `shared_ptr` only needs the type to be complete at the point of creation which allows this data structure. A plain `Node*` would also have worked, but then you would have to manage the memory manually.

Answer (score 1):

A naive implementation of xml: Node extends a list of itself

```
  class Node :
     public std::unordered_map< std::string, std::list< Node > >
  {
  public:

     Node( const std::string & tag_ ) : tag( tag_ ){}

     void print( const std::string & indent ) const
     {
        std::cout << indent << '<' << tag;
        if( ! attributes.empty())
        {
           for( std::unordered_map< std::string, std::string >::const_iterator it2 = attributes.begin(); it2 != attributes.end(); ++it2 )
           {
              std::cout << ' ' << it2->first << "=\"" << it2->second << "\" ";
           }
        }
        std::cout << '>' << std::endl;
        if( ! text.empty())
        {
           std::cout << indent << text << std::endl;
        }
        for( Node::const_iterator it1 = begin(); it1 != end(); ++it1 )
        {
           const std::list< Node > & lst = it1->second;
           for( std::list< Node >::const_iterator it2 = lst.begin(); it2 != lst.end(); ++it2 )
           {
              (*it2).print( indent + '\t' );
           }
        }
        std::cout << indent << "</" << tag << '>' << std::endl;
     }

     std::string                                    tag;
     std::string                                    text;
     std::unordered_map< std::string, std::string > attributes;
  };

  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {
     Node title( "title" );
     title.text = "Title of the html page";

     Node head( "head" );
     head["title"].push_back( title );

     Node html( "html" );
     html["head"].push_back( head );

     Node body( "body" );
     body.attributes["bgcolor"] = "#F0F0F0";
     Node p1( "p" );
     p1.text = "Creativity and imagination are limitless.";
     body["p"].push_back( p1 );
     Node p2( "p" );
     p2.text = "Don't listen to the annoying guys who say your projects are dreams";
     body["p"].push_back( p2 );
     html["body"].push_back( body );

     html.print( "" );

     /* Result:
     <html>
             <head>
                     <title>
                     Title of the html page
                     </title>
             </head>
             <body bgcolor="#F0F0F0" >
                     <p>
                     Creativity and imagination are limitless.
                     </p>
                     <p>
                     Don't listen to the annoying guys who say your projects are dreams
                     </p>
             </body>
     </html>
     */
      return 0;
  }
```

Since no virtual method at all are defined, no need of virtual destructor.

Comment: Undefined behavior: `RecursiveMap` isn't complete when you use it to instantiate `std::map`.  (But I don't think you'll even get that far; the template itself is infinitely recursive, which means that the compiler is going to need more memory than you've got to instantiate it.)

Comment: At first look, yes, but just for fun I've compiled it and run it with VisualC++ 2010: it works! I don't know why...

Comment: It mostly depends on the implementation of the map, since some implementations of some of the containers do not require the type to be complete.  For example, the implementations provided by [Boost.Containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/container/containers_of_incomplete_types.html) can operate on incomplete (at time of declaration) types.

Comment: I've just compilet it with g++ 4.7.1 and ... it works! Anybody have explanation?

Comment: Inheriting from `std::map`, *really*? You should avoid inheriting from types that were not designed to be extended.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: why? Is that a rule, written in the "Real Big Book Of The Rules" ;-) The judge is the compiler and... the time to market!

Comment: @Aubin: If you are happy with undefined behavior in your program good luck. I can tell you that would not pass a code review in my office.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can write the actual type in a fully type-safe way in
C++, because all of the types used when instantiating a template must be
complete when you instantiate the template, and what you basically need
to do is something like:

```
typedef boost::variant<Value, std::map<Key, ExtendedValue> > ExtendedValue;
typedef std::map<Key, ExtendedValue> MyMap;
```

This causes a recursion in the template dependencies: in order to
instantiate `std::map`, `ExtendedValue` must be complete, but in order
to instantiate `ExtendedValue`, `std::map` must be complete.

You should be able to create a less type-safe version using:

```
typedef std::map<Key, boost::any> MyMap;
```

As long as all you put into the map have type `Value` or `MyMap`, this
should work.  (I've done something similar in Java, where the mapped
type was `Object`.)

Alternatively, you could map to a boost::variant which contained a
pointer to the map, rather than the map itself.  Even this is difficult
to name unless you you wrap the map in a class, however.  You can easily
forward declare a class, and use pointers to it, but you can't declare
an instantiation of a template until the types used in the template are
at least known.  So you'ld have to write something like:

```
class MyMap;
typedef boost::variant<Value, MyMap*> ExtendedValue;
class MyMap : private std::map<Key, ExtendedValue>
{
public:
    using ...;
};
```

Since you have to use pointers, this might be the way to go anyway; you
could then wrap the member functions you need to ensure correct member
management as well.  (In which case, a function like `operator[]` would
probably have to return a proxy, so that you could intercept writes, and
do the allocation.)

Answer (score 0):

Short of Algebraic Data Types, a recursive variant can fulfill your needs:

```
using data_type = boost::make_recursive_variant<
    Value
    , std::map<Key, boost::recursive_variant_>
>::type;
```

[Demo on LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3fea84270bfa739ff575262d65bb408f).

Note that this allows for values whose 'shape' (in other words, the depth of recursion) is not known until runtime.

There are other ways to declare and use recursive types using Boost.Variant though, I'd advise you to [check out the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.recursive) to find out which is the most appropriate for your case.

(In particular by using `std::map<Value, data_type>` as the top-level type rather than `data_type` itself I forbid leaves, i.e. values with shape just `Value`. But that's just for the convenience of having the `std::initializer_list` constructors of `std::map`.)